# Jquery datetime picker timezone

Tags: javascript, jquery, timezone, datetimepicker

I am using Jquery datetime picker. `$('.datepicker').datetimepicker();` I need to set timezone. Like **America/New_york** Is there any way to give in options ? Currently it is taking my system timezone.

Comment: Can you specify which is the datetime piicker you are using?

Comment: I am using Jquery datetime picker.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://momentjs.com/ is great library for timezone conversions.

```
var newYork    = moment.tz("2016-06-01 12:00", "America/New_York");
var losAngeles = newYork.clone().tz("America/Los_Angeles");
var london     = newYork.clone().tz("Europe/London");

newYork.format();    // 2016-06-01T12:00:00-04:00
losAngeles.format(); // 2016-06-01T09:00:00-07:00
london.format();     // 2016-06-01T17:00:00+01:00
```

and

By default, moment parses and displays in local time.

Hope help you.

Comment: Great ! ! It helped  . .